# Bash: process all files in a directory

Tags: linux, bash

How would I apply a logic to all files in a directory and pipe the final output of each input file to  a separate file?
Something like below

```
cut -d, -f2 input1.csv | awk 'END{print NR}' > input1_count.csv
```

(actual command is long, but I used above for simplicity to better understand the logic to all the files in a directory)

Comment: Have you tried [xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) ?

Comment: No, I am new to bash

Comment: I used it as an example to create the context for the question (chain of commands)

Comment: ```ls ./ | xargs -I {} cp -u {} /destination/path``` is iterating over all files given by ```ls``` and then ```cp``` logic is being applied on all of them. ```-I``` flag is required for command construction. ```-u {}``` is your iterator.

Comment: Take a look at find. Find/exec pattern might be useful for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `for`-loop over the filenames:

```
shopt -s nullglob # enable nullglob
for f in *.csv; do
   cut -d, -f2 "$f" | awk 'END{print NR}' > "${f%.csv}_count.csv"
done
shopt -u nullglob # disable nullglob
```

The glob pattern `*.csv` expands to a null string with `nullglob` enabled (instead of a literal and probably non-existing filename `*.csv`). 
In the loop, apply the pipeline of commands to each filename and redirect the output to a new filename.

The [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) `${f%.csv}`
removes the shortest suffix pattern `.csv` from the filename.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "glob pattern *.csv expands to null string with nullglob enabled" and how it helps.

Comment: You can make the whole replacement in the substitution: `${f/%.csv/_count.csv}`, where `/%` anchors the pattern at the end of the string.

Comment: @mobileDev If the glob doesn't match anything, the default behaviour is to expand to the literal string `*.csv`; with `nullglob`, it expands to the empty string instead and the loop is skipped.

Comment: So just by adding `shopt -s nullglob` it doesn't become a non-dup answer. Not sure what prompts it.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `for` loop should do the job:

```
for f in *.csv; do
   cut -d, -f2 "$f" | awk 'END{print NR}' > "${f/%.csv/_count.csv}"
done
```

This assumes you have `.csv` files are present in current directory. If files may not exist then use any of these `shopt` above `for` loop:

```
shopt -s failglob    # return error when glob matching fails
```

or

```
shopt -s nullglob    # be silent when glob matching fails
```

Comment: How is output file name being created? What does ```f/.csv/_count.csv``` mean? I don't understand the syntax that went into output filename

Comment: `"${f/.csv/_count.csv}"` replaces `.csv` with `_count.csv` to make it output file name as desired.